# Quickblox sdk is not supporting in Micromax Asus devices

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

Am working on a app in which am using quickblox for chat. everyhing is working fine on all devices but except all micromax and Asus devices its not working

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: unable to login to quickblox through application. in these devices

Comment: 01-18 11:17:33.427 18568-19463/in.techchefs.talktemple D/QBASDK: Connecting to chat..
 D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process in.techchefs.talktemple :5222 
01-18 11:17:33.463 18568-19463/in.techchefs.talktemple I/System.out: [socket][10:36683] exception
01-18 11:17:33.463 18568-19463/in.techchefs.talktemple I/System.out: [CDS]close[36683]
01-18 11:17:33.463 18568-19463/in.techchefs.talktemple D/BaseActivity: Chat login onError: [Connection failed. Please check your internet connection.]

Comment: internet is there along with that i have added internet permission also then all possiblities i had tried but its showing these log in all micromax  and asus devices